# How to connect specific secondary node in MongoDB Replica Set

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-replica-set

I configured cluster with 2 secondary node. So, totally 3 node(1 primary, 2 secondary). My intention is to dedicate one of the secondary node to an application for read only.
But, i could not find the connection property to achieve this. Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: Use tags.......

Comment: Don't really understand your question... You use rs.add(<address>) command to add node to RS

Comment: @JJussi: Edited my query. Can you please help me.

Answer (score 1):

By setting **secondaryPreferred** as the **read preference**.

The documentation statues for **secondaryPreferred** in most situations, operations read from secondary members but if no secondary members are available, operations read from the primary

Note: You can tune your secondary read preference by configuring **maxStaleTimeout**

Please follow below link for more documentation and understanding about read preference https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-preference/

Answer (score 0):

For redirecting read operations to the secondary node(s), specify *readPreference* connection option as either *secondary* or *secondaryPreferred*.
(Ref. https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/read-preference/#read-preference-modes-1)

However, to answer precisely your question, as to how to connect to a *specific* secondary node, do that with the *directConnection* option.
E.g.

```
mongodb://<credentials>@node2.cluster.com/?directConnection=true
```

This is useful for e.g. diagnostic reasons.